# GitLab shell error #<SocketError: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known>

Tags: gitlab

Gitlab server was installed on CentOs 6.7 by Nginx using in local network. I can log in server, add users, projects etc via browser. But users can't push/pull own projects via Windows GIT Bash: 
`$ git push -u origin master`

```
GitLab: Failed to authorize your Git request: internal API unreachable ...
```

To clarify situation on server side I've run:

`sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production` which show the error:

```
...
Running /home/git/gitlab-shell/bin/check
Check GitLab API access: FAILED: Failed to connect to internal API
gitlab-shell self-check failed
  Try fixing it:
  Make sure GitLab is running;
  Check the gitlab-shell configuration file:
  sudo -u git -H editor /home/git/gitlab-shell/config.yml
  Please fix the error above and rerun the checks.
...
```

My  `/home/git/gitlab-shell/config.yml:`

```
user: git
gitlab_url: "https://git/"
http_settings:
  self_signed_cert: false
ca_file: "/etc/nginx/ssl/gitlab.crt"
ca_path: "/etc/nginx/ssl"
repos_path: "/home/git/repositories/"
auth_file: "/home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys"
redis:
  bin: "/usr/bin/redis-cli"
  namespace: resque:gitlab
  socket: "/var/run/redis/redis.sock"
log_level: INFO
audit_usernames: false
```

The error msg in `gitlab-shell.log` is:

```
WARN -- : Failed to connect to internal API <GET https://git//api/v3/internal/check>: 
#<SocketError: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known>
```

`git` alias was written in /etc/hosts and work fine (pinging successfully).  `cat /etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4 
192.168.1.21  git
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

If i change git to localhost in `gitlab-shell/config.yml` I'll get in log:

```
WARN -- : Failed to connect to internal API <GET https://localhost//api/v3/internal/check>: 
#<OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: hostname "localhost" does not match the server certificate>
```

If I change git to IP notation 192.168.1.21 I'll get:

```
WARN -- : Failed to connect to internal API <POST https://192.168.1.21//api/v3/internal/allowed>: 
#<SocketError: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known>
```

SSL is normal. User certificate was set up. On client side `ssh -T git@git` output

```
Welcome to GitLab,...
```

Users can sign in https://git server by browser etc.

Additional info: `sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:env:info RAILS_ENV=production`

```
System information
System:         CentOS 6.7
Current User:   git
Using RVM:      no
Ruby Version:   2.2.3p173
Gem Version:    2.4.8
Bundler Version:1.10.6
Rake Version:   10.4.2
Sidekiq Version:3.3.0

GitLab information
Version:        7.14.1
Revision:       348b983
Directory:      /home/git/gitlab
DB Adapter:     mysql2
URL:            https://git
HTTP Clone URL: https://git/some-group/some-project.git
SSH Clone URL:  git@git:some-group/some-project.git
Using LDAP:     no
Using Omniauth: no

GitLab Shell
Version:        2.6.4
Repositories:   /home/git/repositories/
Hooks:          /home/git/gitlab-shell/hooks/
Git:            /usr/bin/git
```

Can you give me ideas to fix problem (many answers for this question offer adding `localhost 127.0.0.1` to /etc/host , but my version of this file is contain it )?

P.S.
Changing gitlab_url: "https://git/" to gitlab_url: "https://git" or "https://git:8080/" don't solve problem. We have follow msg in log:

```
WARN -- : Failed to connect to internal API <GET https://git/api/v3/internal/check>: 
#<SocketError: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known etc
```

P.S.S. Problem was solved by editing `/gitlab-shell/config.yml`

```
gitlab_url: "https://localhost/"
http_settings:
self_signed_cert: true
```

Only the showed combination of self_signed_cert & gitlab_url can help solving the problem in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved by editing `/gitlab-shell/config.yml`

```
gitlab_url: "https://localhost/"
http_settings:
self_signed_cert: true
```

Only the showed combination of self_signed_cert & gitlab_url can help solving the problem in my case.